# How to perform division between columns and store the answer in a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I just started studying programming using python and I am trying to work out how to smartly perform divisions between columns.

I have a data frame as below:
[Data frame A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jj93x.png)

The numbers(e.g. 101) in the columns are subject IDs.
I want to divide the values in the columns 101-A-5 over the values in the column 101-A-4 and store the answer in the data frame B:
[Data Frame B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDAqC.png)

I want to repeat the process for all the subject IDs. ( in the example I have included only three but in the real data there are 10)
To summarize, I want to do
`{subject_id}-A-5 / {subject_id}-A-4`.

Is there a smart way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a list of all `subject_ids` and then apply the column division to each subject id

```
import random
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "101-A-4":random.sample(range(0,100),100),
    "101-A-5":random.sample(range(0,100),100),
    "102-A-4":random.sample(range(0,100),100),
    "102-A-5":random.sample(range(0,100),100)
})

data = {}
subject_ids = ["101","102"]
for i in subject_ids:
    data[i] = df[f"{i}-A-5"]/df[f"{i}-A-4"]

new_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Which gives:

```
         101       102
0   0.516854  2.307692
1   0.683544  2.222222
2   0.289474  0.073529
3   1.812500  3.478261
4   2.800000  0.085714
..       ...       ...
95  1.695652  0.666667
96  0.666667  2.714286
97  0.897059  0.222222
98  0.447368  1.540541
99  2.742857  0.444444

[100 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked out all right. As a newbie I want to ask how does your mind work when you want to tackle this kind of problem? I mean, what do you think about in your head when it comes to solving a certain problem?

Comment: Practice more questions and learn from other good solutions. Upvote and accept the answer if it has helped you @Ryo_N